# Can val be used as variable in Java?

Tags: java, printing

Is the program legal or not?

I am trying to correct out a statement that will print the value of 3 divided by 2.

I know this isn't correct.

```
System.out.print("The result is" + 3 / 2 + ".")
```

This is my answer.

```
System.out.print("The result is" + val + ".")
double val = 3 / 2
```

Is my answer correct or no? If not, how would I call upon the number?

Comment: Switch the order of your statements and it should work. Think about it, you need to set the value into val before you can pull the value out of it

Comment: `System.out.println("The result is "+(3.0/2)+".");`

Comment: Hey Mack, you need to close this question by accepting 1 of the answers. You can click the check mark beside an answer to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following

```
double val = 3.0 / 2;
System.out.print("The result is" + val + ".");
```

the value `val` must be declared before it is printed. Also you need to make one of the number of type `double` so when the division is done, the answer is a `double` also. Else you lose precision.

the following is also valid:

```
double val = 3 / 2.0;
System.out.print("The result is" + val + ".");
```

if you do `double val = 3 / 2;` then `3/2` division is made with two integers which also give another integer. So `3/2` should give `1.5` but since we are only diving integers, it will omit the `.5` and only give `1`. Then `1` is casted as a `double` and becomes `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is mostly correct:

```
    float val1 = 3;
    float val2 = 2;
    float val= val1/val2;
    System.out.println("The result is " + val + ".");
```

Remember your semicolons.
Also...  You are correct to use a double (or float).  Because otherwise your answer will be truncated.

EDIT:
Actually...  I come to find that trying to do the operation in one shot still truncates the answer.  It isn't correct unless both the values are set as floats.  Then, run the math.

Here is proof:  [online java compiler](http://goo.gl/PjoSqT)

Comment: Okay...  I was only showing a full reasoning behind what I found.  Obviously, your way works too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare first the variables. And if you want fraction numbers you need to do that with them. Need " ; " at the end of every statement. If you try it out in eclipse it will sign error to you when you don't write it where it need to be.

```
 float num1 = 3;
 float num2 = 2;
 float val = num1 / num2;
 System.out.print("The result is" + val + ".");

 // Another way:

 double num1 = 3;
 double num2 = 2;
 double val = num1 / num2;
 System.out.print("The result is" + val + ".");
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
double val = 3.0 / 2;
System.out.print("The result is" + val + ".");
```

Edit:
This is a case of integer division. When division is performed between two integers (here 3 and 2), the output is an integer and the fractional part gets trimmed off. So,3/2 will yield 1 which since you assign to a double variable, becomes 1.0.
When I do 3.0/2, 3.0 is a double value. The output here is a double value too i.e. 1.5; the fractional part is retained. Hence, my solution works.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you explained it.

Comment: It's also incorrect as this will result in an answer of 1.0.